# How do I know if the linear system has a line of intersection?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering how can I determine if there is a line of intersection with any matrix?

For example, if I have the following matrix:

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -3 & -2 & -9 \\
2 & -5 & 1 & 3 \\
-3 & 6 & 2 & 8  \\
\end{array} \right)$$

What does the solution have to look like for me to conclude that there is a line of intersection?

P.S. I know this matrix has a point of intersection but I used this as an example because I didn't know an example for a matrix that had a line of intersection.

Comment: If there are infinitely many solutions, then you are guaranteed to find a line (more generally subspace) of solutions. An equivalent condition is if the rank of the matrix is not full, and at least 1 solution exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existence of a "point of intersection" is the existence of a point $(x, y, z)$ that satisfies the system of equations: a point lying on each line represented by the corresponding system of equations:

$$\begin{align} x - 3y -2z & = -9 \\ 2x - 5y + z & = 3 \\ -3x + 6y + 2z & = 8 \end{align}$$

A unique solution exists (a single point of intersection exists) if the augmented matrix does not reduce to a row of all zeros, and no row has all zeros, augmented by a non-zero entry.

If you obtain a row of all zeros, through row reduction, then infinitely many points of intersection occur (two or more lines will be concurrent): the entries in one or more lines will be a scalar multiple of the entries of another. Put differently, there will be a **line of intersection**.

If the matrix reduces to a row of three zeros, with a non-zero entry in the last column of that row, no solution exists (i.e., no point of intersection exists.)

All these possibilities can be determined by reducing the matrix to [*row echelon form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).

We can reduce your example matrix:

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -3 & -2 & -9 \\
2 & -5 & 1 & 3 \\
-3 & 6 & 2 & 8  \\
\end{array}\right)$$

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -3 & -2 & -9 \\
0 &  1 & 5 & 21 \\
0 & 0 & 11 & 42  \\
\end{array}\right)$$

If reduced further, you'd see that the system represented by the system of equations has a unique **point** of intersection, hence no common line of intersection.

Note that if the last row were $(0\;\;2\;\;10\;\;42)$, we could "zero it" by taking $-2R_2 + R_3 \rightarrow R_3$, and obtain a row of all zeros, since the third row would be a scalar multiple of the second row. In that event, there would indeed be a line of intersection. If any row is a linear combination of the other rows, we have a linearly dependent system of equations: this shows when a row-reduced matrix has a row of **all zeros.** And in that case, there is at least a line of intersection.

Comment: So if the third row of the system is a multiple of the second row or the first row then there is a line of intersection? I'm confused about how it would look in terms of $x$'s and $y$'s and $z$'s. Because for a the final answer for a P.O.I I would just write the solution but what would I write for a L.O.I?

Comment: Very nice Amy and good morning $\ast$

Comment: @gekkostate What one typically does is set, say, $z = \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is any real number. Then express $x, y$ as values in terms of $z = \alpha$. So say you reduce the matrix to the rows the first two rows in the above row-reduced matrix, but the last row is all zeros. Then the solution is given by $z = \alpha, y = 21 - 5 \alpha, x = -9 + 2\alpha + 3(21 - 5\alpha)$, simplifying x, of course. $\alpha$ is then called a parameter.

Comment: Some use the parameter $t$ instead of $\alpha$. [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302072/how-to-interpret-the-solution-of-a-linear-system?rq=1) gives an example of such a system: infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @amWhy, however, in a similar question to this, I also let $\alpha$ to be the parameter, however, the solution of the line of intersection is different from the one when I just do cross product between two of the normal vectors of the plane. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with ranks and Rouché-Capelli (RC) theorem, the following reasoning can be used to answer. The system $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$, where $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix, has solutions if and only if 
$$
r(A)=r(A|\mathbf b)=r,
$$
and in this case you have "$\infty^{n-r}$" solutions. This really means that your solutions depend on $n-r$ free parameters. So, if the rank $r=n-1$, your solution set depends on $n-(n-1)=1$ free parameter or, in other words, it's monodimensional. This helps the intuition that the solution set is indeed a line in this case. Hence, you'll get a line of solutions when the rank of the complete matrix $r$ is equal to the number of unknowns $n$ less 1. As an example, consider the system
$$
\begin{align} x - y & = 2 \\ -2x +2y &=-4
\end{align}
$$
The rank $r(A)=r(A|\mathbf b)=1$ and you can indeed write the solutions set as $x=2+t,y=t$, which is equal to the set of points on the line $y=x-2$.

A more interesting example (I like a lot $A$!) is
$$
\begin{align} 
x +y +z& = 6 \\ 
4x +5y +6z&=15\\
7x+8y+10z&=24
\end{align}
$$
The reduced complete matrix is
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 2 & 3 & 6 \\
0 & -3 & -6 & -9 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
\end{array}\right)
$$
from which you get the solutions $(x=t,y=3-2t,z=t), \forall t$. The solution set can be described in terms of a unique parameter $t$ and it is a straight line in $\mathbf R^3$.